# How to run batch file (As administrator) from Window Service

Tags: windows, service, permissions

I have created a windows service, its running fine.

Now I would like to run a batch file as Administrator using windows service, because without administrator privileges it doesn't return any output.

So please let me know how can I do that. When I run directly using right click, run as administrator its working fine. Batch file as follows:

Runas.exe /noprofile /user:"Laxmilal Menaria" "lm.exe"

Thanks,
Laxmilal Menaria